# recurse through a javascript object adding extra array members if (array.length < 2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

With a nested object such as the 'root' object below; How can I add  a 'dummy' object to those arrays where the length of the array is less than 2.

```
var root = {
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42}
      ]
    },
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42},
        {value: 42}
      ]
    },
    {value: 42}
  ]
};
```

An example of an object i want to insert into arrays where `array.length < 2` :

```
var dummy = {value: 10, dummy: 1};
```

the resulting array:

```
var rootWithDummies = {
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42},
        {value: 10, dummy: 1}
      ]
    },
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42},
        {value: 42}
      ]
    },
    {value: 42}
  ]
};
```

I am trying to use recursion though I still have much to learn:
**EDIT** original addDummies function was checking for `nest.values` when it should have been `nest.children`
**CORRECTED FUNCTION**

```
function addDummies (nest, dummyObject) {

    if (nest.hasOwnProperty("children")) {

        if (nest.children.length < 2) {
            nest.children.push(dummyObject)
        }

        nest.children.forEach(function (item) {

            addDummies(item);

        ;})
    }
}
```

**OLD INCORRECT FUNCTION**
    function addDummies (nest, dummyObject) {

```
    if (nest.hasOwnProperty("values")) {

        if (nest.values.length < 2) {
            nest.values.push(dummyObject)
        }

        nest.values.forEach(function (item) {

            addDummies(nest.values);

        ;})
    }
}
```

this attempt does not seem to call addDummies recursively
nor does it have any checking that the value of 'values' is actually an array (and therefore has a length property).

Comment: Why are you adding the dummy-object to the outer `children` array? It already has 3 elements. Or do elements containing children themselves "not count"?

Comment: Of course there is no recursion going on: you're checking `.hasOwnProperty('values')` whereas the property `values` is not set in the `root` object: you'll have to check for `children`, too

Comment: @Šime - my mistake with example data. I have removed the mistaken dummy object in the root object

Comment: I thought that I am recursively calling the function `addDummies()` within the forEach method @Elias

Comment: Is it working now? (after you change `addDummies(item);` to `addDummies(item,dummyObject);` of course, there is nothing to push if you don't pass the argument in the recursive call...

Comment: @Elias, can't seem to get this working with those changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close; Changes:

- remove the syntax error `;})` on the third to last line
- use a `while` loop instead of appending just one dummy object

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/V3bvV/

```
var padNode = function padNode (node) {
    if (node.children) {
        while (node.children.length < 2) {
            node.children.push(dummy);
        }  

        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            padNode(node.children[i]);
        }        
    }
};
```

Comment: the `while` loop is good because I can see how easy it would be to pad with up to any number of items: `node.children.length < 4` for example , and so it makes sense why you named the function as 'pad'Node

Comment: @jbabey, Your solution does rely on a global variable, so the op should either use a parameter, or [a closure](http://jsfiddle.net/V3bvV/1/). I've taken the liberty of updating your fiddle for use of a closure

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem i usually operate under the assumption that all code is inside an IIFE, which is probably not a good idea when i am providing code for others.

Comment: Sadly, JS being as popular as it is, compared to the number of people who know the value of scopes, the danger of (implied) globals and the power of closures, that's not the safest of assumptions... I wasn't trying to be a smart-ass, though, just my 2cts in another desperate attempt to [smugness]educate the public[/smugness] :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem no, i completely agree. [smokey-the-bear-voice] only you can prevent global namespace collisions!

Comment: @jbabey: LOL, [full-on-yoda-mode]"use strict" of great assistance, because hard to alter the global object is[normal-yoda-mode]

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a working solution:

```
var root = {
  children: [
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42}
      ]
    },
    {
      children: [
        {value: 42},
        {value: 42}
      ]
    },
    {value: 42}
  ]
};
var dummy = {value: 10, dummy: 1};

function addDummies (node) {

    if (node.children) {
      if (node.children.length < 2) {
        node.children.push(dummy)
      }  
      for (var i=0, len=node.children.length; i<len; i++) {
        addDummies(node.children[i]);
      }
    }
}

addDummies(root);
console.log(root);
```

​
And the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kKrFC/

I'll edit with an explanation of why it wasn't working for you in an hour or so, I have to go now.

**EDIT**

The `hasOwnProperty` check is not necessary, as you only need to check it when you are looping through the object's members. What you need to do is send as the function parameter each of the elements in `children`, as each one of this is *like a root node*. That is precisely the idea of recursion (at least in this case).